# Why is my Vista is so slow to go to standby?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, standby

I always have a dozen of apps open on my Core2 Duo 2.4Ghz /3gb memory laptop, normally about 60-70% is memory is in use.

The problem i have is that when i decide to put Vista to stand by it may take up to 2-3 minutes, during this process it heavily trashes the harddrive saving something.

Why does it need to save anything? Isnt it supposed to keep it all in memory?
I guess the problem is that it locks my account and saving stuff to the disk.
Is there any way to speed it up?

Update:

- Same issue after switching to Windows 7
- Same issue after upgrading to
  4gb then 6gb then 8gb of RAM.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's going to sleep mode and not hibernate?  How are you putting it into sleep mode?

Comment: well, press on a power a button and it goes to hybernate, closing lid - it goes to sleep with On light flashing time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved once I have disabled paging file in Windows. As before on my desktop, disabling page file made things on the laptop much faster as well.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Vista has a feature a feature called "Hybrid  Sleep" which makes it copy the contents of the RAM to the hard drive just like it would when you hibernate. The up side is that if your computer loses power (batter dies, comes unplugged, etc) you can still resume. The downside is, as you have noticed, that going into standby takes just as long as hibernation would.

I am not running Vista atm, so I'm not sure where you would find this option.

Comment: this is very good point. i've checked related settings and unfortunatly it is disabled already.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run any virtualisation software? I typically find that if I have VMware Workstation open and running a couple of VMs, it adds several minutes to the standby time.

Other than that, 60%-70% of what total? If you have a lot of intensive applications open, it could just be that they take a lot of time to get into a standby state.

Comment: i do infact (Microsoft Virtual PC), always on. It has 1 gig of memory allocated (of total of 3Gb). I'll try without it, thanks.

Comment: If you pause the VM before you go to suspend, it should be quicker - I find most VM software seems to be a lot slower when you suspend the machine than just suspending them individually.

Answer (score 0):

here's an illustrated guide: **[Disable Hybrid Sleep Mode in Windows Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-hybrid-sleep-mode/)**